# Rust Polars Library Concatenate columns of different types

Tags: rust

I have a csv file called test.csv which i am reading into a dataframe using polars. I have a  name,month,day,year as my headers month is a string day/year are i64. i want to concatenate the three columns together in rust to have a single column called date in pure rust. Below is what i have so far to just print the dataframe to the console.

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn read_from_file(path: &str) -> Result<DataFrame, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    let df = CsvReader::from_path(path)?
        //.infer_schema(Some(100))
        .has_header(true)
        .finish()?;

    println!("{}", df);

   Ok(df)
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // Read CSV file into a DataFrame
    read_from_file("./data/test.csv")?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Hi there.

You're probably not looking for _concatenate_, which has a very specific meaning about putting things next to each other, like two strings into one.

Rather, you might want to look at the `map_multiple` function:
https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/fn.map_multiple.html

Comment: Do you want the resulting column to have type String, Date, or DateTime?

Comment: i think probably datetime would be the best outcome. i am coming from python so the learning curve is a little steep getting the same code to work from python to rust.

Answer (score 0):

In polars (and SQL), we get specific columns by calling [select](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/selecting_data/selecting_data_expressions.html).

```
df.select([col("ham"), col("spam")]);
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want to build a column using the content of 3 other columns. I'm unable to make it work with an "eager" dataframe. There's almost no documentation on Rust polars (although it's a Rust project). But here's an example with a "lazy" dataframe.

```
let dates = df
    .lazy()  // No need to call this if df is already lazy
    .select([
        col("name"),
        concat_str([col("year"), col("month"), col("day")], "-").alias("data"),
    ])
    .collect();
println!("{:?}", dates)
```

polars can be complex. I strongly suggest to read the [documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/index.html). You can find one `concat_str` example in this [page](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/notebooks/introduction_polars-rs.html?highlight=concat_str#selection-context).

Comment: so i had to import col like this but now im getting a different error. i think it has something to do with rusts borrow/reference 

use polars::prelude::col;
let df = df.select([col("name"), col("year")]);
     |                 ^^^^^^ the trait `AsRef<str>` is not implemented for `Expr`

Comment: I had the same problem you had. I updated my answer with an actual working example.

Comment: thank you for the help. I'm still having trouble getting it to compile i think because i am not handling the return types properly in my fn main() which is on me me to learn rust better which is why i asked this question. simple things i can do in python for instance i want to try writing it in rust to help me learn the language better.